# Calcular distância percorrida no android

Tags: android, maps

Desenvolvi um aplicativo que uma das funcionalidades que ele tem é calcular a distância percorrida pelo usuário, para tal utilizo um `Service` e a API `LocationListener` para solicitar updates de localização do usuário.
No método `onLocationChanged` eu faço o calculo da distância percorrida e salvo no banco local. O que está acontecendo é que algumas vezes essa conta da distância percorrida está dando bem acima do estimado.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {

        if (startCounter) {

            if (!isFirstLocationFinded) {
                latlon = new double[]{location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()};
                isFirstLocationFinded = true;
            } else {

                double distance = calculateDistance(location);

                    //save in database
                    TrackingRace track = database.find(TrackingRace.class, ID);
                    if (track == null) {
                        TrackingRace trackingRace = new TrackingRace(ID, distance);
                        database.save(trackingRace);
                    } else {
                        double oldDistance = track.distance;
                        double totalDistance = distance + oldDistance;

                        TrackingRace trackingRace = new TrackingRace(ID, totalDistance);
                        database.update(trackingRace);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private double calculateDistance(Location location) {

    double[] latlonNew = new double[]{location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()};

    double distance = 0;

    Location locationA = new Location("point A");
    locationA.setLatitude(latlon[0]);
    locationA.setLongitude(latlon[1]);

    Location locationB = new Location("point B");
    locationB.setLatitude(latlonNew[0]);
    locationB.setLongitude(latlonNew[1]);

    distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);

    latlon = latlonNew.clone();

    return distance;

}
```

Comment: A função calculateDistance irá sempre calcular uma linha reta do ponto A ao ponto B. É isso mesmo que você quer?

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo Utilizei esse exemplo https://github.com/vkuzub/Taximeter/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vkuzub/taximeter/service/CounterService.java

Comment: Entendi. Você calcula essa distancia de tempo em tempo e vai acumulando. É isso?  E você compara o que mesmo para concluir que esta acima do esperado?

Comment: Isso eu calculo a cada 7 segundos mais ou menos, é como se fosse um taxímetro. A comparação é que existe uma estimativa de distância percorrida, o usuário informa o destino.. E eu tenho o ponto de partida e de finalização do percusso. No final o valor calculado é bem maior do que a estimativa.. @ReginaldoRigo

Comment: Você esta calculando uma linha reta inicialmente, o que não acontece durante o percurso. Por isso que a distancia acumulada é maior.

Comment: Na estimativa é utilizado a API do Maps para calcular como se fosse um percusso pelas ruas mesmo... E a diferença é bem grande, por ex:
O que era pra dar 3km dá 18km.. @ReginaldoRigo

Comment: hmmmm. Então o erro esta na rotina que acumula. Ela teria de fazer isso: Inicialmente tem o ponto A. Depois de 7 segundos tenho o ponto B. Calculo a distancia do ponto B ao Ponto A. Acumulo e substituo o ponto Inicial A pelo ponto B.